# What is the JIRA Query to get time spent by an user in a day.

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jql, jira-rest-java-api

I have a Jql to get time spent by a user in jira. But this below query is returning total time spent by an user in particular user story or subtask instead of day wise.

I mean if an user story created one day before,and user had logged some time in that. On present day also user had logged some time.

So when am trying to get current day time spent by an user am getting both day time from this below query.

```
worklogAuthor = 'User Name' AND worklogDate >= "2017/11/20" AND worklogDate <= "2017/11/20"
```

So can someone please help me to get exact time spent by a user in a day. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can't get a sum of the worklogs for a specific day. JQL is a filter on the issues that match the JQL. So, you will get a list of issues where a Worklog was created by specified user and matches the date that you have indicated. If the user worked on three different issues that day, you will see three different issues returned. You can't get the worklogs in the Issue Navigator.

Instead, you would you have export the issue data to Excel (export all fields) and then parse the worklogs (they show up as a column called Log Work) to get the specific worklogs for that date.

Alternatively, you can get the worklogs via the REST API and do your calculation that way.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
assignee = currentUser() AND worklogDate >= startOfDay() AND issueFunction in aggregateExpression("Total tracked", "timespent.sum()")
```

I hope that helps.  You can adjust the parameters to get ranges or different users.

Comment: Hi it's only returned the list of issues worked by this user during this period, it's not returning the sum

Comment: With this JQL as well, we are unable to retrieve the time logged for particular day by a user. It retrieve the sum of all the time logged for the particular task during the past as well.